# Unable to run powershell script in IIS hosted .net web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run a `powershell` script(script is used to updated a excel sheet data) in `.net web api` project as mantioned bellow,

```
 var ps1File = @"C:\ActiveLKTel.ps1";
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
 {
      FileName = "powershell.exe",
      Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted \"{ps1File}\"",
      UseShellExecute = false
 };
 Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This works fine when I run `.net web api` project in localhost, but this does not work when I deploy the `.net web api` project in `IIS`

Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `-File` parameter.

```cs
var ps1File = @"C:\ActiveLKTel.ps1";
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
     FileName = "powershell.exe",
     Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File \"{ps1File}\"",
     UseShellExecute = false
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

When you run the script in IIS, it is not working because the script will run under the context of the user on the IIS app pool. Does this account have permission to:

- Run the script
- Carry out the actions within the script